# Spring Security Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, spring-security, junit4, spring-test

I have Unit test for testing form based authentication

```
 this.mvc.perform(formLogin("/login").user("user_login", "rusti_1993@mail.ru").password("user_password", "password")).
                andExpect(
                        authenticated()
                                .withRoles(
                                        "VISITOR"
                                        , "ORGANIZATION_PUBLISHER"
                                        , "ORGANIZATION_ADMIN"
                                        , "BILITON_ADMIN"));
```

and it throw exception :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: [ROLE_VISITOR, ROLE_ORGANIZATION_PUBLISHER, ROLE_ORGANIZATION_ADMIN, ROLE_BILITON_ADMIN](db authorities) does not contain the same authorities as [ROLE_VISITOR, ROLE_ORGANIZATION_PUBLISHER, ROLE_ORGANIZATION_ADMIN, ROLE_BILITON_ADMIN]
```

I cant understand why! They are the same collections. And I found that spring-security-test uses

> java.util.Collection.containsAll(Collection c)

method

Comment: How did you implement spring security authentication? is there a `UserDetailsService` or anything else? add more details

Comment: When you authenticate are you using a custom implementation of GrantedAuthority or are you using SimpleGrantedAuthority? If you use a custom implementation of GrantedAuthority, you will need to use authenticated().withAuthorities(...)

Comment: I have custom enum which implement GrantedAuthority